# Is "thanks for all." correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I "thanks for all" correct/meaningful/grammatical? It was said by a student thanking their teacher after a course. That was the whole sentence. It used as an alternative for "thanks for everything".

Answer (score 1):

"All" *what*?

A more natural expression is

> Thanks for all you've done for us

or

> Thanks for all your help.

But it could just be something the kids say nowadays.  Slang is not really either *correct* or *incorrect*, but it's best if you don't use it until you're very familiar with it.

Comment: The student wasn't a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the student was not a native speaker (or maybe you didn't hear the whole thing?).

**"thanks for all"** is an incomplete sentence. As Andrew said, "all" of what?

**"Thanks for all your help", "Thanks for all your advice", "Thanks for your help today.".** These would all be better options and explain exactly what you are thanking the person for doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all is an incomplete sentence because the all has to be followed with a description of the deed that is being acknowledged.

Example: Thanks for all that you have done for me

If one simply wishes to thank everyone in the audience, some of the correct usages are

> A big thanks to all of you
>
> Thank you one and all
>
> Thank you all
>
> Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62190/discussion-on-answer-by-george-is-thanks-for-all-correct).